# How to count HTML Tags if I have dynamic changes in these tags?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to count some tags in this page [Link](https://www.musala.com/careers/join-us/?location=Sofia)

I am trying to count the tags of opening positions so, I tried this code
using java to count but I always find my count is = 0;

```
    public By cardsNumOfPositions = By.xpath("//div[@class='card']");
    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(cardsNumOfPositions);
    int countelements = element.size();
```

And I write this function to count:-

```
    public void printCountElements() {
        System.out.println(countelements);
    }
```

Everytime the count is 0, I searched for an Iframe but I didn't find any.
so how can I get the size of this element?

Comment: Show the full code, is `countelements` a global variable?

Comment: @Thecave3 yes the problem was this countelements should be inside the method, or it should be public by another way. but all I did is putting this line List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(cardsNumOfPositions); inside the method, it works fine now 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can make `countelements` as a static variable.

like this:

```
static int countelements;
```

now since it's static, its value will persist. You can call it like this:

```
public void printCountElements() {
    countelements = element.size();
    System.out.println(countelements);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it doesn't look like there's anything wrong with it if what you're trying to achieve is to count the number of elements on the page matching that xpath.

The xpath also looks good, and I've tested it and it works. I can see that iframes exist on the page, but it doesn't look like these elements are within those iframes, so it doesn't look like stepping into an iframe would be required.

Are there sufficient waits in place, to make sure these elements are fully loaded before we're trying to find them? I'm worried that we're trying to put these elements into a list before they've loaded.

Failing that, what I'd check next is run the same test, but this time using the parents (or parents parents) of this element, and follow it up the chain to see if we can get any hits whilst running the code.

Comment: The problem was with the list outside the method

Comment: List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(cardsNumOfPositions); I put this line inside the method it worked fine.